# how to split a set with duplicate data into several groups?

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I say I have a data array like [500,500,520,520,520,535,535...],I wanna split the array into several groups so that the sum of each group is between 3000 and 3100(it's ok if a set or two do not qualify), and more importantly, the result groups can be clustered into several clusters and the groups in the same cluster are very similar and the groups in different group are really different from each other.The less the number of clusters, the better the result is.

For example, group A:[500,520,535,700,800],group B:[500,520,535,720,800]. These the sums of two group are both between 3000 and 3100, and they are very similar to each other and can be cluster to the same group because of the similarity between them.
If possible,we should avoid putting the same number more than once in the same group to reduce the number of clusters.

would anyone give me an idea or direction or some keywords how to solve such problem? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your input is not a set because it has repeated values. Jaccard distance is defined for sets. Do the output groups need to be sets? Are you guaranteed that no element in the input is repeated more times than the number of output sets?

Comment: I have reedit the question, would you review it and make some comment?

Comment: It's still pretty unclear. For instance, what do you mean by "Similar"? Similar in number of elements? Sum of elements? Many common matching elements?

Comment: There's also a lot of vague-ness here. Is it better to have more sets but all of them qualify, or fewer sets with some that don't? It might help if you told us the context of this problem, as well as the specific metrics you're trying to fulfill.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please copy it exactly. If this is a personal or work problem and you're able to give context or details about exactly what you're hoping to achieve, please do so.

Comment: I post a new link which elaborate the above question more clearly, would you mind take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74705858/how-to-cut-the-steel-pipe